# $destroy event is triggered after element is detached in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a directive inside `ng-repeat` and I'm listening on the `$destroy` event.
Usually this event is triggered while the element is still attached to the DOM, but specifically on `ng-repeat` when the event is triggered the element is already detached from the DOM.

Is there any way to get a destruction event while the element is still attached?
Here's a fiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/z5tLhe14/

As you can see when the `$destroy` event is triggered the element doesn't have a parent.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Doesn't really make sense having an event `$beforeDestroy`

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using twitter bootstrap tooltip and if the tooltip is shown and the item that has the tooltip is no longer in the list, angular removes it from the DOM but the tooltip stays because no mouseout was triggered. And if I try to trigger it manually it doesn't work because the element is already detached from the DOM

Comment: Wouldn't have those issues if you got rid of `bootstrap.js` completely and used `angular-ui-bootstrap`.

Comment: I know :) But it's an old project so I can't really change those things

Comment: Why can't you store parent before hand if that's what you are looking for? Also element still exists inside destroy...see http://jsfiddle.net/z5tLhe14/2/

Comment: Saving the parent doesn't matter.. I don't need the parent.. I need the element to be attached to the DOM so that the destroy function of the tooltip would work

Comment: Create a better demo that includes  tooltips. My fiddle update has element reference so not entirely clear what problem is

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) mention that "in AngularJS, there is also a $destroy jQuery event, which can be used to clean up DOM bindings before an element is removed from the DOM" -- so if you're interested in the element being removed rather than the scope being destroyed, you could use `element.on('$destroy', callback)`.

Comment: Also note that tooltips can be set to be in body as opposed to element for cases such as this. Shouldn't be too hard to make it work using what's is already available

Comment: Thanks @pdenes it solved my problem :)